# change the values of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix 100x50. What I want to do is to change the cells having the value > 0 to 0, and the cells having the value=0 to 1. I know its simple, but if anyone could please advise how to do it without loops.

Comment: What to do with negative values? Or are there none?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
iiPos = M>0;
iiZeros = M==0;

M(iiPos) = 0;
M(iiZeros) = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a neat way of doing it, using a [logical not](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/not.html), if there are only non-negative numbers:

```
M =
   1   2   0   2
   2   1   2   2
   0   1   2   1
   1   0   1   2

M = ~M;    
M =
   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0
```

If you have negative numbers as well, then:

```
M = 
   0  -1   0   3
  -3   0  -1   0
   0  -2   0   1
   1   0  -1   1

M(M >= 0) = ~M(M >= 0)    
M =
   1  -1   1   0
  -3   1  -1   1
   1  -2   1   0
   0   1  -1   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Why so complicated?

```
M = (M == 0);
```

For this, the zeros have to be exact zeros. If they are only approximately zero, use

```
M = (abs(M) < eps);
```

Comment: @LuisMendo  The question specifies that the matrix contains values > 0 and values = 0, nothing else. If there values < 0, it wouldn't be clear what to do with them.

Comment: @ADonda I don't see that the question really specifies that. And of course in that case you would do _nothing_ with those values. ... But I agree with you that the OP's idea is probably that there are no negative values

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeMat = size(mat); % Obtain the size of the matrix
final = zeros(sizeMat); % Create a zero full matrix.
idxZero = find(Mat == 0); % Find where = 0;
final(idxZero) = 1; % switch to 1.
```

Comment: @Andy, Just for your information, Matlab comment is `%`. I just did like that because the user can copy-paste the code into command window easily without getting error.

Answer (score 0):

For the general case with negative numbers:

```
A = A.*(A<0) + (A==0);
```

Comment: That's assuming negative values should be preserved.

Comment: Well, if _nothing_ is said about negative values, of course they should be preserved! :-)

Comment: If *nothing* is said about negative values, of course there are none! ;-) I guess we'll have to ask the OP.